# Word Add-in Word Count Excluding Tables & Headers

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-count

I'm VERY new to Word add-ins, but saw them in VS as (falsely) advertised as C# projects, and as someone who's dabbled in that for a while I thought I'd give it a go to save myself time instead of having to open up Notepad and doing the math by selecting various elements.

I then realised that pretty much all the functional code is in js, and we don't get along!

After trying and failing for the last day, I've decided to just ask.

My functional code for just trying to get the total wordcount is below, but even this doesn't seem to work.

```js
function calcWordCount() {
        Word.run(function (context) {

            var range = context.document.body;

            var totalWC;

            context.load(range, 'text');

            var words = range.text.split(/\s+/);

            totalWC = words.length;

            context.load(totalWC, 'font');

            $("#fullWC").text(totalWC);

            return context.sync();
        })
        .catch(errorHandler);
    }
```

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing with this, but did find this vb macro do what what I am looking to do here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excluding-words-from-the-word-count/e6f59014-66f2-4b43-83d2-df52f7b4da5b
Problem is, due to security I can't run macros for my work, so I need to be able to do this within an add-in.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, and how I can:
A) count the total words
B) identify table and header word-count and minus that from the total

I'm completely lost here, the Office documentation for this seems to be VERY sparse.

Comment: «due to security I can't run macros for my work, so I need to be able to do this within an add-in» Seems strange you can use unauthorised add-ins but not macros... Regardless, VBA can be deployed via an addin - it's quite common.

Comment: FWIW if C# is your tool of choice and you are allowed to use VS, the most straightforward route would probably be to write either a C# console app or forms app that just uses Word's object model to do exactly what you would do in VBA. AS long as your environment allows it (it would indeed be strange if VBA was disallowed but you could do anything you wanted in VS, but system Admin people may be more concerned about "foreign" VBA delivering smalware to your system than they are about people writing their own code.

Comment: If you can't do that or use some other mechanism to code against the traditional object model, and have no option other than Office-JS *and* your code is just for you, you may be better off using Script Lab than VS. I think you can get it here: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-GB/product/office/wa104380862 . IME the projects VS generates are all about scaffolding, whereas Script Lab lets you focus on the Java/TypeScript. I think when you've sorted out your programming platform it would be a bit easier to make suggestions about the code, because the two object models are quite different.

Comment: @macropod  Our admins aren't fans of macros due to malicious code being able to be hidden in Word docs. They don't mind us creating our own tools (I've made a couple of our internal software packages before) as long as we use our companies signing on it and provide full code for them to look over.

Comment: @jonsson I ended up using the Word Add-in option that allows pure C# and XAML, won't be usable on the online version of Word or on Mac, but suits my purposes. The documentation even for that though isn't amazing.

Comment: @AtlasTabula OK, glad you sorted something out.